# Is there a way to migrate from HCL with the Terraform provider to YAML?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform

Currently I have a deployment of an applicationn done with HCL in Terraform. Is it possible to have the terraform provider for Kubernetes output to a directory or in some form the YAML that it is sending to kubernetes?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to get Terraform to output to YAML but if you have access to the k8 cluster you can easily get the YAML for a deployment/pod. See this existing SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43941772/get-yaml-for-deployed-kubernetes-services).

Comment: `-o yaml` adds a lot of stuff not part of the original Terraform HCL.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to have the terraform provider for Kubernetes output to a directory or in some form the YAML that it is sending to kubernetes?

You can do this with a combination of a [file](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/local/latest/docs/resources/file) provider and the [`yamlencode()`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/yamlencode) function.

Let's say you have a [`kubernetes_deployment_v1`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/deployment_v1) and you want to write the yaml description of it to a file:

```
resource "kubernetes_deployment_v1" "this" {
  ...
}

resource "local_file" "that" {
   content = yamlencode(kubernetes_deployment_v1.this.spec)
   filename = "${path.module}/deployment_spec.yaml"
}
```